# Is it possible to use a format string and a sans serif font?

Tags: python

Basically, is it possible to use a format string to lay out a out string like below with a sans serif font instead of a monospace font. That is, is there a way to find the length of the text not in characaters but in terms of "space" they take up? The desired outcome being that the 2nd column starts as soon as the first one ends?

[image: How it looks with monospace font]

```
result_string += f"{movie.name:<25} | {movie.rating:>}\n"
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're printing to console, I don't think so - I'd advise looking into [monospace sans-serif fonts](https://www.1001fonts.com/monospaced+sans-serif-fonts.html) to use for your terminal.

Comment: It is for a GUI if that helps? I am using appJar but if you have a tKinter solution I can probably find my way from there.

Comment: Simplest way to do it in a GUI is simply to put each point of data in a separate label, and manually control the size and position of the labels

Comment: Ok, that sounds out of my scope (I am assuming your would need to create a label generator class for all letters in a string and then position them using a constructed x y system)  as this is a high school exercise. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You wouldn't have to do it that way with `tkinter`, which has "layout managers" to automate much of what needs to be done and it supports using different fonts on its interface widgets. Suggest you give it a shot and post another question with some code if you get stuck. There are literally hundreds of online tutorials and command references.

Comment: I will look into it. Thank you.